# How to find a variable that matches the number of unoccupied dwellings?

Tags: c

I was given an assignment asking me to create a program that reads the number of apartment buildings and the number of people living in each apartment. Then we have to calculate the minimum, maximum and average number of residents + the number of unoccupied buildings/dwellings. The last point of the assignment causes me a problem, as I can't figure out how to implement it. The most I could do is to make the program write which apartment is unoccupied, which is still insufficient. I will need a little help.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    //Write an algorithm that reads the number of bytes in the apartment building and the numbers living in each apartment. 
    //Calculate and write down the average, maximum and minimum number of inhabitants, the number of unoccupied dwellings.

    int n,i;
    printf("Enter the number of apartments in the apartment building:\n");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    int p[n],s=0;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        printf("Enter the number of residents in %d. apartment:\n",i+1);
        scanf("%d",&p[i]);
        s+=p[i];
    }
    int min=p[0];
    for(i=1;i<n;i++)
        if(p[i]<min)
        {
            min=p[i];
        }
    printf("Minimum population: %d\n",min);
    int max=p[0];
    for(i=1;i<n;i++)
        if(p[i]>max)
        {
            max=p[i];
        }
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        if(p[i]==0)
        {
            printf("%d. apartment is unoccupied.\n",i+1);
        }

    printf("Maximum population: %d\n",max);
    printf("Average population: %.2f\n",(float)s/n);
    printf("Number of unoccupied apartment: %d\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Instead of writing it out, count it, storing it into a variable. You just need a plaint `int Vacancies = 0;` before you start your count loop for the vacant apartments.

Comment: Try counting the number of apartments which have 0 occupants.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is straightforward enough. You just need to be able to *increment* a counter, whose initial value is zero, and report its value at the end.

```
int empty = 0;
for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    if(p[i]==0)
    {
        empty++;
    }

printf("Maximum population: %d\n",max);
printf("Average population: %.2f\n",(float)s/n);
printf("Number of unoccupied apartment: %d\n", empty);
```